# Random results when exit of a frame within a listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I want to insert items in a list and for that I have put a text box inside a frame that I place over the desired item in the list. All this because you cannot put a textbox on a list in Zorder 0.

The results I get are not always the same, sometimes the ListBox_Exit event trigger first and sometimes the Frame_Exit. I cannot find the reason.

I send source code and screenshots of the userform with objects and results.

There must be data to fill the lists in the first 4 rows of columns A and B of Sheet1.

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJRDf.jpg)

[UserForm & Objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccqyq.jpg)

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByRtP.jpg)

```
Option Explicit
Private mlngListIndex As Long
Private mbNotExecute As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With UserForm1.lstLeft
        .List = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4").Cells.Value2
    End With
    With UserForm1.lstRight
        .List = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B4").Cells.Value2
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub lstLeft_Click()
    Debug.Print "lstLeft_Click"
    If mbNotExecute Then Exit Sub

    With UserForm1
        If .fraLeft.Visible Then Exit Sub
        mbNotExecute = True
        .lstRight.ListIndex = .lstLeft.ListIndex
        mbNotExecute = False
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub lstRight_Click()
    Debug.Print "lstRight_Click"
    If mbNotExecute Then Exit Sub

    With UserForm1
        If .fraLeft.Visible Then Exit Sub
        mbNotExecute = True
        .lstLeft.ListIndex = .lstRight.ListIndex
        mbNotExecute = False
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub fraLeft_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Debug.Print "fraLeft_Exit"
End Sub

Private Sub fraRight_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Debug.Print "fraRight_Exit"
End Sub

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    With UserForm1
        If .lstLeft.ListIndex <> -1 Then
            .lstLeft.AddItem "", .lstLeft.ListIndex
            .lstRight.AddItem "", .lstLeft.ListIndex - 1
            .lstLeft.ListIndex = .lstLeft.ListIndex - 1
            mlngListIndex = .lstLeft.ListIndex
            Call Edit
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub Edit()
    Dim ObjTop As Single
    With UserForm1
        If .lstRight.ListIndex <> -1 Then
            ObjTop = .lstLeft.ListIndex * 10 + .lstLeft.Top + 1
            .fraLeft.Visible = True
            .fraLeft.ZOrder 0
            .fraLeft.Top = ObjTop
            .fraLeft.Left = .lstLeft.Left + 2
            .fraLeft.Height = 10
            .fraLeft.Width = .lstLeft.Width - 3
            .txtLeft.Top = -3
            .txtLeft.Left = -3
            .txtLeft.Width = .fraLeft.Width + 3
            .txtLeft.Height = 16
            .txtLeft.Text = .lstLeft.List(.lstLeft.ListIndex)

            .fraRight.Visible = True
            .fraRight.ZOrder 0
            .fraRight.Top = ObjTop
            .fraRight.Left = .lstRight.Left + 2
            .fraRight.Height = 12
            .fraRight.Width = .lstRight.Width - 2
            .fraRight.Height = 10
            .txtRight.Visible = True
            .txtRight.Top = -3
            .txtRight.Left = -2
            .txtRight.Width = .fraRight.Width + 2
            .txtRight.Height = 16
            .txtRight.Text = .lstRight.List(.lstRight.ListIndex)
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything happens because I used the UserForm1 "Show" method in "vbModeless" mode. If I use it with "vbModal" the events trigger well.